# Error type object 'modelo' has no attribute 'objetcs' Django, Python3x

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

Tengo un error del cual no tengo idea porqué.

En mi proyecto en Django, tengo dos aplicaciones a y b.
En la aplicación b, estoy tratando de acceder desde una función en el views.py  de la misma aplicación a todos los elementos de un modelo definidos también en la misma aplicación b.

Este es el código en el models.py:

```
class modelo1(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        verbose_name='Nombre')
    description = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Descripción",
        null=True, blank=True,
        max_length=999)
    date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.now)
```

En el views.py tengo definida una vista en Login donde intento traerme todos los datos del modelo mencionado:

```
from aplicacion.models import modelo1

class Login(LoginView):
    template_name = 'login/views/login.html'

    def get_modelo1_data(self):
        modelo_data = False
        if len(modelo1.objetcs.all()) > 0: # Aqui tengo el problema
            modelo_data = True
    
        return modelo_data

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['modelo1_data'] = self.get_modelo1_data() # Acá llamo la función
        return context
```

Sin embargo al cargar la vista login donde está definida la función antes descrita me levanta este error:

```
type object 'modelo1' has no attribute 'objetcs'

  File "/home/.../views.py", line 44, in get_context_data
    context['modelo1_data'] = self.get_modelo1_data()
  File "/home/.../views.py", line 32, in get_modelo1_data
    if len(modelo1.objetcs.all()) > 0:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /core/login/
Exception Value: type object 'modelo1_data' has no attribute 'objetcs'
```

El error en sí es :
**Exception Value: type object 'modelo1_data' has no attribute 'objetcs'**

Incluso cuando pruebo con cualquier modelo de mi aplicación a también me da el ,mismo error.
No comprendo porque dice que no tiene el atributo objects que tienen todos los modelos.

Que puede estar pasando??

Comment: Te sirve [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52180681/django-type-object-template-has-no-attribute-objects) o [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35543695/type-object-x-has-no-attribute-objects/35544035)?

Comment: @gcoronel99 Ninguna. la primera opción no es mi caso, y la segunda ya lo he intentado :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La cuestión es que tienes mal escrito objects:
Tienes:

```
modelo1.objetcs.all()
```

Sería:

```
modelo1.objects.all()
```

Básicamente es un error de sintaxis.
Espero que con esto resolvamos el problema, si no es así, por favor comentame. Saludos

Comment: Jajajajaja era eso, eso pasa por no concentrarme